# How to hide error code in frontend

Tags: magento2

Does anyone have any idea how to hide error codes on the website (frontend) if any get and instead show the client a general graphic, e.g. that we have a temporary problem, we are working on it,

Comment: redirect to 404 page when error occur !!

Comment: Doesn't that already happen in production mode? You just need to set a [custom error page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024199/nginx-customizing-404-page)

Answer (score 1):

Addition on the tips below: make sure the following line is commented:

> ini_set('display_errors', 1);

to

> #ini_set('display_errors', 1);

in app/bootstrap.php

Also what is said above: setting your site in production mode should disable the display of (most) errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do following things.

1. Set your website into the production mode using this command.

> php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production

2. If you want your custom design, then modify the default 404 page.